# How to edit single Entity in GAE (Python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm doing my first small project in Python(GAE), and there's no difficulty in operating GAE's database using queries. But when it comes to editing single Entity I face a problem.
All I need is a simple counter which would increment on every site visit.
So I create an Entity (this is done once, just to create Entity, then this code is removed from project) by:

```
counter_name = 'default_counter'

def counter_key(counter_n=None):
   return db.Key.from_path('Counter', counter_name)

class Counter(db.Model):
    amount = db.IntegerProperty()

class CounterClass(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        counter = Counter(counter_key(counter_name))
        counter.amount = 0
        counter.put()
```

It is ok.
But when I try to increment it, using:

```
counter = db.get(db.Key.from_path('Counter', 'default_counter'))
counter.amount += 1
counter.put()
```

I get this Error.

> ERROR    2011-09-06 21:49:41,562 _webapp25.py:464] 'NoneType' object
>   has no attribute 'amount' Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp_webapp25.py",
>   line 703, in **call**
>       handler.post(*groups)   File
>   "H:\gae-bin\counter.py", line
>   48, in post
>       counter.amount += 1 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no
>   attribute 'amount'

I checked different variations, but still cant change Entity's value.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you use to create the `Counter` entity is likely wrong. What it does is creating a `Counter` entity whose **parent** is `Counter` with keyname equal to `default_counter`. That doesn't seem to be what your want, as evidenced by code you use to update the counter.

You need to assign the keyname of your `Counter` entity via one of the following ways:

```
counter = Counter(key_name='default_counter')
# or
counter = Counter(key=db.Key.from_path('Counter', 'default_counter'))
```

Note that in general it is bad idea to have a visit counter like that. GAE entities have a limti for 5 updates per seconds so if you ever scale beyond that, you will run into problems.

Common technique for dealing with the update limitation is to use **sharding counters** as described here: http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html . A combination of datastore and memcache is also an option if you don't mind occasionally losing some counter increments.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually creating the entity with that key.  You should change this:

```
counter = Counter(db.Key.from_path('Counter', 'default_counter'))
```

to this:

```
counter = Counter(key=db.Key.from_path('Counter', 'default_counter'))
```

And since you're immediately setting the amount to `0`, you could do that when initializing the entity as well:

```
counter = Counter(key=db.Key.from_path('Counter', 'default_counter'), amount=0)
```

**Please also note** that this is not a very good way to create a counter on App Engine.  You'll want to use a technique like [sharded counters](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters.html) or [something using memcached](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/High-concurrency-counters-without-sharding)

Comment: Thanks.
But the Entity is created anyway. I can see that in localhost/_ah/admin in database indexes.
Thanks for the links. I'll try those.

Comment: Or you could just do `Counter(key_name='default_counter', amount=0)` - there's no need to specify the whole key.